The speed of light in vacuum (but which speed?)
Since there are several different definitions of speed describing light propagation like Group velocity, Front velocity and Phase velocity.
Which speed is meant when the phrase "The speed of light in vacuum" is used?
Like for example the second postulate of special relativity by Einstein that "the speed of light in free space has the same value c in all inertial frames of reference" - which speed was he referring to?
As I currently understand it - it is the maximal speed at which an information can be sent from one place to another. But if it is so then isn't the addition of "in the vacuum" (or "in free space") redundant?

Calling the constant $c$ the "speed of light" is something of a misnomer. In special relativity, time and space are taken on equal footing. To achieve this in a physical sense, one needs a "conversion factor" between time and space; It turns out that this factor is $c$. Of course, this conversion factor must be the same in all reference frames, otherwise, it would be very hard (if not impossible) to build a consistent theory.
Furthermore it can be shown that a massless particle in the absence of external influences (i.e. the vacuum) will always propagate with speed $c$. As is known, photons are massless particles, and since electromagnetic radiation was the first phenomenon discovered to propagate with speed $c$, the constant was named "speed of light". Of course, the speed of electromagnetic waves can be altered by introducing external influences, so the somewhat cumbersome "in the vacuum" had to be added to the name of the constant. But this does not mean that there is any significance of light per se to this speed. In the vacuum, a gravitational wave also travels with $c$, for example.
You are right about $c$ being the highest speed at which information can propagate. I think from this it should be easy to figure out which part of a light wave (first) propagates with $c$.

But Einstein's postulate is about light. At the time he came up with it, spacetime geometry was not a concept.

In the link for Front velocity we can read: "In fact, the earliest appearance of the front of an electromagnetic disturbance (the precursor) travels at the front velocity, which is c, no matter what the medium.". So it confused me why we have to add "in the vacuum" when there exists a signal that its front speed is always c even if there is no vacuum.

@azerbajdzan I meant in the vacuum. You initially asked which of the three types of speed associated with an electromagnetic wave is the speed of light as meant by Einstein. This is the front velocity of the wave in the vacuum.

@JohnDoty yes it was, the entire theory of special relativity boils down to the geometry of spacetime being that of $3+1$-dimensional minkowski space. Einsteins postulate is about $c$, not actual, physical light, which basically never goes through a vacuum and therefore never actually travels at $c$. This was well known before Einstein.

@pauina No. Einstein's original reasoning was based entirely on electrodynamics, not geometry. The title of his paper is "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", and it starts describing an electrical experiment. The geometric interpretation came from Minkowski.

The history doesn’t really matter. Einstein had the first word on relativity, not the last word. Now the theory of relativity is recognized as a theory of spacetime and $c$ is recognized as the invariant speed. The association with light is historical and relativity would remain intact if the photon were found to have mass (and therefore travel slower than $c$)

@Dale The history is everything, because it's all about how the theory emerged from the fundamental observations and experiments. Without that understanding, physics is mere mathematics, unsupported by anything real.

The OP is about Einstein's second postulate of relativity, which is explicitly about light, not spacetime geometry.

@JohnDoty Einstein may have first postulated it about light, but $c$ is a much more fundamental quantity than just "the speed at which light travels". In a modern perspective on physics, it should be thought about as the conversion factor between space and time, which also happens to be the speed of massless particles (such as photons). Insisting on it being "the speed of light" only leads to confusion.

@paulina Theory is not fundamental: it is a story about experimental results. Theory changes: Galileo's gravity was supplanted by Newton's, which was supplanted by Einstein's (and will probably be supplanted by something else). But Galileo's experimental results remain, as valid and fundamental as ever.

@JohnDoty Einstein's postulates are theory. As experimental data has been added (e.g. other forces that were unknown at Einstein's time) it became clear that the experimental data is better explained by understanding relativity as a theory of spacetime and not as a theory about light. But if you want to ignore all scientific developments since 1905 (both theory and experiment) then that is hardly unexpected. The rest of the scientific community has moved on in the last hundred years.

@Dale I'm quite aware of that. But Einstein's postulates are what Einstein wrote, not more recent elaborations. Minkowski's geometric interpretation of Einstein's result was simply a reformulation of Einstein's theory, fundamentally based on electromagnetic phenomena. That the theory also works for subsequent experimental results is gratifying, and those are now part of the foundation. But the theory didn't materialize out of thin air: it is fundamentally based on experiments.

@Dale OK, how would you state Einstein's second postulate (the topic of the OP)?

In a vacuum an electromagnetic wave has the same phase and group velocities, so the speed of light in a vacuum is unambiguous.
If the light is propagating through some medium this is generally not true. The electric field of the light interacts with the electrons in the medium and in effect the photons and electrons get mixed together. See Can speed of light be $c$ in air or other medium? for more on this. The group velocity of the resulting mixture is less than $c$  and the phase velocity is greater than $c$. So the speed of light is only $c$ in a vacuum.
Having said this, in relativity the $c$ isn't special because it's the speed light travels at, or indeed that any massless particle travels at. $c$ is a constant associated with the geometry of flat spacetime. For more on this see What is so special about speed of light in vacuum?

Einstein used the constant $c$ that occurs in Maxwell's equations for electricity and magnetism, the idea being that Maxwell's equations should remain true under any change of inertial coordinate systems. This idea fails when Newtonian coordinate change laws are used; but it succeeds when Lorentzian coordinate change laws are used, as long as that same constant $c$ is the one that is built into the Lorentz coordinate change formulas.
It was already known, before Einstein, that the constant $c$ in Maxwell's equations was the speed of the "electromagnetic waves" that are predicted by those equations. And it was also already known that light waves are one special type of electromagnetic wave. The reason that "vacuum" is an issue is that the crap that pollutes a vacuum (e.g. the odd hydrogen ion here, or lump of dielectric there) can interrupt the transmission of those waves; in other words, Maxwell's equations only predict electromagnetic waves of speed $c$ if there is no other "electromagnetic crap" for those waves to interact with.
So that's why the "speed of light in a vacuum" is the speed that Einstein was referring to in his formulation of special relativity.

For light in a vacuum, those speeds are experimentally as close to the same as can be measured. Based on this, and other experimental results, the theory assumes they are the same.
